# CSS for selecting based on a data-* attribute containing an array of values?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I need to select a HTML element based on data in an attribute called "data-attributes". In Firefox's DOM Inspector, the attribute value appears like this:

```
<div data-attributes="[{"Id":50,"Code":"LIC","ShowInSessionFilter":false}]">
```

I have tried using a CSS selector like below, to no avail:

```
div[data-attributes~="LIC"]
```

So I assume the attribute value is not a string as such, but a javascript object being shown by the Inspector as a Json string. The question is, how do I select the node based on one of the key/value pairs in the object it contains? Is this possible in CSS?

Comment: The `~=` would not be the proper check, as that looks for "[a space separated list of words](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/attributeselector)."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The attribute is just a string as far as css is concerned. You could probably use `div[data-attributes*="LIC"]`, though that isn't checking the json key - the *= operator in CSS just means that the attribute includes that substring. So it'd also match ["LIC2":"foo"] and similar.

Maybe `[data-attributes*=":\"LIC\""]` would be good enough for your case though.

Comment: "The attribute is just a string as far as css is concerned." Correct.